# "Изучая микробы" или "Изучая микробов"?

Tags: склонение, окончания, родительный-или-винительный, одушевленность

В сочинении я написал: "Изучая микробы, я пришел к выводу..."
Репетитор меня поправила, что надо писать "Изучая микробов..." Кто прав и почему?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае никто не прав и все правы.

[**Изучать микробов или микробы? Одушевленность существительных**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=68) (Грамота.ру):

> 3. Когда возникают колебания и варианты?
>
> «Все колебания между грамматической одушевленностью и неодушевленностью (обнаруживающиеся в вариативном образовании винительного падежа) объясняются именно неоднозначностью в оценке объекта как живого или неживого.
>
> Часть таких случаев относится к тем объектам, принадлежность которых к животным или растениям может показаться неочевидной: *амебы, бактерии, бациллы, вибрионы, вирусы, инфузории, **микробы*** и др. (*изучать микроб**ов** и микроб**ы***)...»

[**микроб**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1) (Викисловарь):

винительный падеж, ед. число:  микро́ба // микро́б
винительный падеж, мн. число:  микро́бов // микро́бы

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Изучая микробов, я пришел к выводу...**

**Микро́бы** — собирательное название **живых организмов**, которые слишком малы для того, чтобы быть видимыми невооружённым глазом.

Сочинение, вероятно, как раз было написано по научной дисциплине (биологии), поэтому здесь более уместен вариант, которым пользуются **врачи, ученые, биологи, а не те, кто выражается общелитературно**. И микроскоп у школьника, вероятно, тоже был.

Даже сочетание "***изучать микробы***" на слух воспринимается некорректно.

Comment: Сочетание "изучать микробы" на слух воспринимается корректно. *Панков. Мы изучаем микробы, чтобы лучше с ними бороться. Знать, как их уничтожить* (https://books.google.ee/books?id=Qc9eDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%22&source=bl&ots=ZhQdP5O1Fh&sig=ACfU3U1n_TCQBiej1cQn9FA7xr1OIJh1lw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDiOa88Zn5AhWQ6CoKHSpvBzIQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%22&f=false)

Comment: Меня удивляет отсутствие логики в ответах. Автор вопроса спрашивает, как правильно писать в его случае. Но четкого ответа нет. Начинается поиск правил, рекомендаций в источниках, в данном случае довольно противоречивых. И нет логики, никакой. Стилевые различия? Но здесь как раз научный стиль, микробы в биологии изучаются как живые существа. Так зачем нам стиль общелитературный? Да и стили по смыслу можно характеризовать хоть как-то, есть версия? Тоже нет? Ну давайте я предложу, а вы меня поправьте.

Comment: В науке микробы определяются как живые (одушевленные) существа, а в общелитературном смысле это среда, обычно болезнетворная для человека. Тогда микробы можно воспринимать как нечто неодушевленное. И я с удовольствием послушаю ваше мнение по этому вопросу. «Мы изучаем микробы (сообщество микробов), чтобы лучше с ними бороться»?  В этом тексте это как раз микробная среда как угроза нашему здоровью, так что все корректно.

Comment: Да, меня тоже удивляет отсутствие логики в Вашем ответе. Как это нет четкого ответа? *Вывод: верны, конечно, оба варианта, но предпочтительней неодушевленная форма — изучать микробы*. В Вашем же ответе нет ни ссылок, ни правил, только предположения и домыслы (сочинение, по биологии? Это вряд ли! По биологии обычно пишут рефераты, а про микроскоп школьник вообще ничего не говорил), цитаты из интернета и моего комментария (кстати, Вы их не оформили как цитаты) и просто собственные ощущения ("на слух воспринимается некорректно"). Чем же Ваши ощущения лучше, грамотнее моих?

Comment: Почему предпочтительнее неодушевленная форма? Почему учебный реферат нужно писать "общелитературно"? Как различаются стили по семантике?  Как зависит выбор формы от контекста, от ситуации? Можете ответить на эти вопросы, в книжки и справочники не заглядывая. Думаю, что вряд ли,  там ответов нет. Тогда к чему этот разговор, который вы начали?  Я же  всего лишь дала альтернативный ответ.

Comment: У нас нет никакого учебного реферата. Есть сочинение, которое обычно и пишется общелитературным языком. И никакого разговора *я* не начинала, только высказалась, что сочетание "изучать микробы" на слух воспринимается корректно (это *мое* мнение. Вам можно *альтернативничать*, а мне нельзя?). Закончим...

Comment: Да уж чего там, надо договорить. У вас нет реферата, а у них, может, есть. Педагог видел письменную работу и сказал, какой вариант подходит. А вы не видели, но даете рекомендации.   Сочетание "изучать микробы"  рассматривалось в заданном тексте, а не вообще.  Вот теперь, пожалуй, все.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы все-таки ориентировалась на Розенталя, а не на Викисловарь.
В словаре управления:
[микроб](http://endic.ru/rusman/Mikrob-2182.html)
Вин. пад. мн. ч.: **микробы** и (реже) микробов. Уничтожать микробы.

Вот еще, из справочника:

> 1. **Некоторые существительные склоняются по типу одушевленных и неодушевленных**, например: *изучать живые **существа** — изучать живых **существ**, рассматривать **бактерии** — рассматривать **бактерий**, исследовать **бациллы** — исследовать **бацилл**, уничтожать **микробы** — уничтожать **микробов***, то же в отношении слов ***зародыши, личинки, вибрионы, полипы*** и некоторых других. Первые формы употребляются в общелитературном языке, вторые связаны с более архаическим или профессиональным употреблением.

[§ 153. Формы винительного падежа одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xxxvi-formy-imen-sushchestvitelnyh/ss-153-formy-vinitelnogo-padezha-odushevlennyh-i-neodushevlennyh-sushchestvitelnyh)

Вот еще, из Нацкорпуса: [уничтожать микробы](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B) — 2; уничтожать микробов — 0.

― Дело в том, что в сыворотке крови, слюне и других жидких фракциях обнаружены особые физиологически активные вещества, способные **уничтожать микробы** и нейтрализовать токсины. [Еремей Парнов. Александрийская гемма (1990)]

Вывод: верны, конечно, оба варианта, но предпочтительней неодушевленная форма — *изучать микроб**ы***.

Comment: Римма, конечно, Розенталь, как говорится, наше всё. Но... 1. Сначала я дал ссылку на Грамоту, а на Викисловарь сослался потому, что там, как мне кажется, приводятся все альтернативные варианты. Этот источник беспристрастен и основан на многочисленных источниках. 2. Розенталь... реже / не реже – ну откуда нам знать сейчас эту частотность? 3. Микробов всё-таки относят к живым организмам, а если человек изучает их, то, по моему субъективному мнению, должен уважительно относиться к ним ("профессиональное употребление"). Я бы писал так: *изучаю микроб**ов***.

Comment: Не согласна. *Изучать микробы* можно и по книгам. А сказать "Я вижу микробов" могут лишь единицы, имеющие в своем распоряжении наисильнейший микроскоп.

Comment: Впервые в распоряжении врачей оказалось оружие, массово убивающее микроб**ов**. [Александр Волков. Антибиотики: кризис среднего возраста // «Знание-сила», 2013] ...существует доза, способная убить микроб**ов**, но при этом не навредить человеку. [Ю. Шуляк. Это война! Учёные против микробов // «Кот Шрёдингера», 2017] Что они задумывают, принимаясь мастерить микроб**ов** по своей прихоти? [Александр Волков. Синтетическая мания биологии // «Знание - сила», 2011]

Comment: Это никак не противоречит Розенталю. Посмотрите в примерах: так говорят врачи, ученые, биологи, а не те, кто выражается *общелитературно*.

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не против Вашего ответа и Розенталя! Просто еще раз хочу акцентировать внимание на Викисловаре, где приводятся две равноправные формы. Вот и говорю, что автор вопроса может обосновать свой выбор исходя из своих представлений об изучаемом объекте.

Comment: Кстати, я биолог по образованию. :)

Comment: Ух ты, здорово! Вот поэтому тебе и ближе одушевленная форма -ОВ (она ведь *первой* указана в ВС). Биологи — они такие... живое любят. Шучу.